# Merge two dataframes on a condition that a value in the first dataframe is a sub string of the values in the other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

so let's say I have a dataframe `retailer_info` like this:

```
    price   product_name    url
0   5005    Intel Pentium Gold G5400 3.70 GHz Processor https://www.theitdepot.com/details-Intel+Penti...
1   7150    Intel Core i3-9100F 3.60 GHz Processor  https://www.theitdepot.com/details-Intel+Core+...
2   8210    AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega 8 Graphics   https://www.theitdepot.com/details-AMD+Ryzen+3...
3   8415    AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega 8 Graphics   https://www.theitdepot.com/details-AMD+Ryzen+3...
4   10330   AMD Ryzen 5 1600 3.2 GHz Processor  https://www.theitdepot.com/details-AMD+Ryzen+5...
```

I have another dataframe, `cpu_info` like this:

```
    Type    Part Number Brand   Model   Rank
92  CPU YD1600BBAEBOX   AMD Ryzen 5 1600    93
96  CPU YD250XBBM4KAF   AMD Ryzen 5 2500X   97
108 CPU YD3200C5FHBOX   AMD Ryzen 3 3200G   109
129 CPU YD150XBBAEBOX   AMD Ryzen 5 1500X   130
138 CPU YD2400C5FBBOX   AMD Ryzen 5 2400G   139
139 CPU YD2200C5FBBOX   AMD Ryzen 3 2200G   140
153 CPU YD130XBBAEBOX   AMD Ryzen 3 1300X   154
```

Now for every value in the series `cpu_info['Model']`, I need to check if it is a sub string for any value in the series `retailer_info['product_name']` and if it is, I want to merge the column `url` in the df `retailer_info` to the dataframe `cpu_info`.

Expected Outcome:

```
    Type    Part Number Brand   Model   Rank    url
92  CPU YD1600BBAEBOX   AMD Ryzen 5 1600    93  https://www.theitdepot.com/details-AMD+Ryzen+5...
96  CPU YD250XBBM4KAF   AMD Ryzen 5 2500X   97  NaN
108 CPU YD3200C5FHBOX   AMD Ryzen 3 3200G   109 https://www.theitdepot.com/details-AMD+Ryzen+3...
129 CPU YD150XBBAEBOX   AMD Ryzen 5 1500X   130 NaN
138 CPU YD2400C5FBBOX   AMD Ryzen 5 2400G   139 NaN
139 CPU YD2200C5FBBOX   AMD Ryzen 3 2200G   140 https://www.theitdepot.com/details-AMD+Ryzen+3...
153 CPU YD130XBBAEBOX   AMD Ryzen 3 1300X   154 NaN
```

I realised `new_df = pd.merge(cpu, it['product_name', 'url'], on='', how='left')`
 only works if you want to merge only based on column values. I'm unsure how to achieve the the result I wanted. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work

```
def find_url(model_name):
    try:
        return retailer_info[retailer_info['product_name'].str.contains(model_name)]['address'].values[0]
    except:
        return None

cpu_info['url'] = cpu_info['Model'].apply(model_name)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but I don't fully understand this expression. I get that `retailer_info[retailer_info.product_name.str.find(x).ge(0)]['url']` returns a Pandas series. So the expression `cpu_info.Model.apply(
    lambda x: retailer_info[retailer_info.product_name.str.find(x).ge(0)]['url'])` returns a series for each value in `cpu_info.Model`? But then I get what you're doing with `.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]`, you're getting all the links from different columns to the first column and are returning that series. But I don't understand the part where the links are spread across different columns.

Comment: That was because, every time the lambda function was returning a pandas series of shape `(n,1)` and not just the required URL. I've updated the code and simplified it. Sorry for the bad code earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Can add more that one conditional:

```
dicc = pd.Series(retailer_info["url"].values,index=retailer_info["product_name"]).to_dict()

cpu_info["url"] = ""
for index, row in cpu_info.iterrows():
    for key in dicc:
        if row["Brand"] in key and row["Model"] in key:
            cpu_info.at[index, "url"] = dicc[key]
            break
```